# Which Database should I use for small network application

Tags: c#, database

I have an application (currently in foxpro) that uses about 12 tables that can be networked.
The tables are related in various ways, but not unduely complex - more like a customer ordering system

I want to rewrite it in C# using MS Visual Studio.
The Application is desktop only but with up to 5 users able to access it at any given time.

The question is which DB should I use?
It needs to be:

- Easy to install with the application.
- Support sharing from up to 3 or 4 computers

I have looked at SQL Express but the sharing issue looks to be fairly complex and installation for SQL on a server computer is required.
DB4O seems to be for more media rich applications.

I am fairly new to C# (and now getting long in the tooth as well) so I need this to be a reasonably painless way to achieve what I already have in Foxpro.

Some may ask why change - well, there are things that we want to be able to add in the future that would stretch Foxpro too far.

I have spent a couple of weeks researching this and now would really appreciate any help that people could offer.

Comment: Go with SQL Server Express - it's free, it's easy to use (once set up), it's reliable in a networked environment, plus you'll learn skills you can later use on "real" SQL Server instances, if needed. Take the plunge, learn the installation and setup, and then you'll be fine

Comment: SQL Express is not suitable as it will not work on shard drives outside of a domain - as far as I can ascertain at this point.

Comment: SQL Server Express needs a **proper server** where it can be installed on - and quite frankly, if you have multiple concurrent users, that's the only way to get this to work reliably. Any file-/directory-based solution will cause you grief and corruption problems - sooner or later....

Answer (score 5):

My policy: If the job can be handled by [SQLite](http://sqlite.org) (for .NET one option is [System.Data.SQLite](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki)), use that.  On the surface, it sounds like this can.

> **SQLite is [...] a self-contained, serverless, zero-configuration, transactional SQL database engine.** SQLite is the most widely deployed SQL database engine in the world. The source code for SQLite is in the public domain.

Comment: From the [SQLite FAQ](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q5): "People who have a lot of experience with Windows tell me that file locking of network files is very buggy and is not dependable. If what they say is true, sharing an SQLite database between two or more Windows machines might cause unexpected problems." Embedded databases are usually not a good fit if you need to share the database.

Comment: A quick google produces no reports of this kind of issue actually occurring with SQLite, and that FAQ looks somewhat outdated and it's not clear if it's discussing NTFS at all.  I've had generally good results with file-shared databases, including in substantially heavier usage environments than this user is suggesting.  I have never, however, used SQLite in that way.

Comment: SQLite seems to be just what I need, ,but I have run into 2 difficulties with it: 1.  I keep getting errors with visual Studio 2010 implementation, even after reading some of the articles relating to this.  2.  Handling of "Money" Data.  This is a comercial app ie. it deals with items Pricing and discounts, toals and GST.  The way that SQLite handles this is still unclear with some saying just use an integer and store the vale as cents.  So I still need to resolve this issue.  Would really appreciate some feedback on this one as Money calculations are at the heart of the system

Comment: SQLite doesn't have a currency type (or, in fact, very many types at all!).  You are probably best off storing as integer and formatting for display and entry.

Answer (score 1):

Just to stir the pot a bit, if you're connected to the internet you could give a [SQL Azure Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg619386%28v=BTS.70%29.aspx) a whirl.

No server required; multiple connections not a problem; scalable; maintainable; etc.  Synch it with a local database later if you change your mind.  MS has a 90 day trial run which would probably suit your investigative purposes.

Downsides are well-covered elsewhere, but mainly it's that internet outage renders your app offline.

It's actually not a bad option if you're looking to get your upgrade up and running quickly.

Comment: +1 good option indeed ! You offload all the "keep the servers running" tasks to a professional data-center and concentrate on your own business logic!

Answer (score 0):

try MySQL, i think there is an easy way to make the database shared along the network (i think it's in the installation process)

Answer (score 0):

mysql... use this driver ODBC drive so that your .NET applications can connect to mysql [mysql odbc driver](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/)

Comment: I'd argue that non-Microsoft databases aren't a good suggestion for someone with little experience with the platform. Tutorials will point you to features such as LINQ-to-SQL which doesn't really work out of the box for anything but SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Server Compact Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/get-sql-server.aspx) supports multiple clients **on the same machine**. If you need to connect to the database from multiple computers, you should probably stick with Express Edition.

Comment: This would not work as I am looking at accessing the data from multiple (2-5) computers.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a Document Database rather than the typical Releationl Databases being discussed here?

One that is very friendly in the .Net space is RavendDB.

Work through this simple "Hello World" tutorial (shows some basic CRUD coding) in Visual Studio to get a feel for how it works: http://ravendb.net/tutorials/hello-world

Answer (score 0):

LocalDB would be a good solution